# How to set Java home path during building Android gradle file via command line?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want specify the Java home path during building my Android gradle via command line; for example,

```
gradle build -d path of jdk
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [gradle documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html):

> The following properties can be used to configure the Gradle build
>   environment:
>
> ...
>
> **org.gradle.java.home** Specifies the Java home for the Gradle build
>   process. The value can be set to either a jdk or jre location,
>   however, depending on what your build does, jdk is safer. A reasonable
>   default is used if the setting is unspecified.
>
> **org.gradle.jvmargs** Specifies the jvmargs used for the daemon process.
>   The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings. At
>   the moment the default settings are pretty generous with regards to
>   memory.

In other words, you can do it simply by running

```
gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=<java home path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, one of the following should work.

As Amnon Shochot suggested, set the `-Dorg.gradle.java.home` flag. This is probably preferable in most cases.

If you want to have use a particular JDK throughout, set the JAVA_HOME variable appropriately before executing gradle.

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/specialJava/
$ gradle build
```

If you don't want to change the environment, try adding the below to your build.gradle script. It should affect only the compiler used to compile Java code, nothing else. So Gradle doesn't run inside this particular JDK, but it will use it for compiling.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = "/usr/local/specialJava/bin/javac"
}
```

(Last option stolen from [here](http://discuss.gradle.org/t/setting-path-to-jdk/6991/4%20here))